# Is the RNN vanishing gradients problem really a gradients problem?

Tags: deep-learning, rnn, machine-learning-model, optimization

It is known that RNNs do not have long memory, that is they do not capture long dependencies.

Usually this is explained by the **vanishing** (or explolding) **gradients** problem - when computing the gradients of the RNN, the early part of the input signal doesn't contribute to the gradient because of many multipications in the back propagation process.

However, I think that it may be only a simptom of the real problem. The gradients are small because the early part of the signal **really does not affect** the output (because of forward multipications). This is not only a point of view difference, it is an essential difference - this is **not an optimization problem but a modeling problem**. I think that even if we had a "magic initializer" that would initialize our RNN with the best possible weights it would still suffer from short memory problems, hence the gradients are not the major problem.

**Is the RNN short memory problem really an optimization problem or a modeling problem?**

To make it clearer - a similar question - Do exist weights such that RNN with those weights has long memory?